# Read whole text file word by word with sorted words with bash

Tags: bash, file

Say I have file `test.txt` with content:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam rhoncus dictum eros, eu molestie lectus cursus sit amet. Aliquam lectus erat, ultricies sit amet venenatis et, tincidunt eget magna.
```

What I need, it is to read whole file word-by-word but... with words sorted. So:

```
Aliquam
Aliquam
consectertur
dictum
...
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
tr ' ' '\n' < test.txt | sort -u
```

Remove the `-u` if you want duplicates

Answer (score 2):

```
for w in `cat test.txt`; do echo "$w"; done | sort
```

Remove punctuation as well:

```
for w in `cat test.txt`; do echo "$w"; done | sed 's,[^a-zA-Z],,g' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tr "[[:space:]]" "\n" < file| sed 's/[[:punct:]]$//' | sort
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -0777 -ne 'puts $_.split.map{ |x| x.gsub(/[[:punct:]]$/,"") }.sort' file
```